# Eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of particle in 2D box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, coordinate-systems, probability

A particle in a 2D potential box has two degrees of freedom. It is bound by the infinite potentials at the boundaries.

Our professor asked us to resolve this into its respective $x$ and $y$ components, so that the problems and solutions would be similar to the one dimensional infinite well problem. So, I wrote Schrodinger's equation for motion in the $x$- and $y$-direction, respectively.
The eigenfunction of the system can be written as:$$\Psi_{{n_{x}}{n_{y}}}=\Psi_{n_{x}}. \Psi_{n_{y}} $$
Where,
$$\Psi_{n_{x}}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \cos\Bigl(\frac{n_{x}\pi x}{L}\Bigr) , \quad n_x=\text{odd}$$for even parity and,
$$\Psi_{n_{x}}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \sin\Bigl(\frac{n_{x}\pi x}{L}\Bigr), \quad n_x = \text{even} $$for odd parity.

And where,
$$\Psi_{n_{y}}(y)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \cos\Bigl(\frac{n_{y}\pi y}{L}\Bigr),\quad  n_y=\text{odd}$$for even parity and,
$$\Psi_{n_{y}}(y)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \sin\Bigl(\frac{n_{y}\pi y}{L}\Bigr), \quad n_y = \text{even} $$for odd parity.

So, the product of the two wave functions, which is the resulting wave function, will be of one of the four forms given below:
$$\sin{x} \sin{y} $$
$$\sin{x} \cos{y} $$
$$\cos{x} \sin{y} $$
$$\cos{x} \cos{y} $$

If we plot these four graphs, we know that we do not get graphs which lie *only* on the $xy$ plane. They *have* $z$-coordinates.

My questions are as follows:

1. The wave function of a particle existing in the 2D plane, has co-ordinates in the 3D plane. What does this signify?
2. On giving it some thought, I came up with a theory that the $z$-coordinate could represent the probability of finding the particle at a point(directly below it) in the $xy$-plane. I'm not 100% sure if this is correct, though.
3. If the second point is true, we must note that the graphs have both positive and negative $z$-coordinates. If it does represent probability, we know we cannot have negative values for it. So we either entirely neglect the negative values (which I find absurd) or we make them positive. And the only ways to do that are by either taking modulus of the product of the wave functions, or squaring them. What is to be done here?
4. If the answer to the above question is squaring, I'm confused. While I am aware that the square of the wave function represents probability, isn't it wrong to square the probability itself (i.e. $z$-coordinate)?

I know that my question is pretty long, but I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out, as my professor wasn't able to give me an answer. Please note, that I am very new to this subject.

Comment: Hint: Go back to the beginning. You start with $\Psi_{n_x,n_y}$. What is that? How does everything else relate to it?

Comment: Hint: your question is not really specific to a 2D box going into 3D. For a 1D box, the graph is two-dimensional, right?

Answer (score 4):

1. No it doesn't.  The spatial coordinates here are $x$ and $y$, which appear in the arguments of the sine and cosine functions.
2. It seems strange to me that you are this far into a course in quantum mechanics and have not yet learned that the wavefunction is the spatial probability *amplitude*.  To obtain the spatial probability *density*, you take the square modulus of the wavefunction $|\psi(x)|^2 = \psi^* \psi$ where the star denotes complex conjugation.  See the wikipedia article on the [Born rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule).
3. See above
4. Again, the wavefunction is the probability amplitude.  Taking the square modulus gives the probability density, and integrating the probability density over some region gives the probability of measuring the particle to be in that region.

Comment: I think I haven't understood what the z-coordinate represents, or even if it represents something. Can you please brief me on this, so that I can grasp your answer better?

Comment: @SmritiSivakumar There simply is no z-coordinate here, so I’m afraid I don’t know what you mean. You could make a 3D graph by plotting $\psi(x,y)$ as a function of the $x$ and $y$ coordinates, is that what you have in mind? If so, as I said $\psi(x,y)$ is the probability amplitude at the point $(x,y)$. It’s the thing you square to get the probability density.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the 3D graph...and I wanted to know what the respective z coordinates meant. What you square to get probability density is a complex number. But the values of z are real. Am I interpreting it wrong?

Comment: @SmritiSivakumar You keep talking about a $z$-coordinate.  There **is no such coordinate** anywhere in this conversation.

Comment: @SmritiSivakumar Perhaps you're confused by the fact that in this particular case, you can take the energy eigenstates to be purely real.  In general, your $\Psi$'s will be complex.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118626/room-for-smriti-sivakumar-and-j-murray

Comment: I have elaborated my question , please look into it here. Thank you!